# if $\dfrac{d\phi}{dx} \leq k \phi$, $\phi(0) = 0$ then $\phi(x) \equiv 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

I need a hint (not a full solution, please) on how to prove the following result:

Prove that if $\left\{ \begin{array}{l} \dfrac{d \phi}{dx} \leq k \cdot \phi\\
\phi(0)=0\end{array}\right., k>0$, then $\phi(x)\equiv 0$

So, obviously, in the case that the equality holds the solution is identically zero. What I'm failing to show is that with such an inequality, the solution $\phi(x)$ is necessarily greater or equal to zero, and lower than the solution where the equality holds (in which case it'll be zero by squeezing).

Please don't post a complete answer, I'm trying to self learn this thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about $\phi(x)=-xe^{kx}$? In general, what can you say about the function $u(x)=e^{-kx}\phi(x)$?

Comment: Hint : Mean value theorem

Comment: Are you sure the problem did not have an assumption $\phi(x) \ge 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes, I have the book where it's from and there is no such assumption.

Comment: @SangchulLee The $\phi(x)$ you posted is not an solution. Also, $u(x)$ is a solution to $u'(x)=k(x-1)u(x)$... is that it?

Comment: @Mand, My example $\phi(x)=-xe^{kx}$ IS a solution: $$\phi'(x)=-kxe^{kx}-e^{kx}\leq -kxe^{-kx}=k\phi(x).$$ Also, note that $\phi$ solves the problem if and only if $u$ solves $u'(x)\leq 0$ and $u(0)=0$. I believe you can come up with non-trivial examples satisfying this.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking on a solution to the problem without the inequality. But on the expression you wrote, shouldn't it be $kx$ instead of $-kx$ on the last exponential (before the last equal sign)?

Comment: @SangchulLee and therefore, the problem is stated wrongly, or missing a hypothesis?

Comment: @Mand, There, I am simply dropping the negative term $-e^{kx}$. I am not sure what you are worried about there. Also, the problem is clearly wrong and need to be fixed. I guess the correct problem should be: $$|\phi'(x)|\leq k\phi(x)\qquad\text{and}\qquad\phi(0)=0.$$ (For example, this version is Exercise 5.26 of [Baby Rudin](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/principles-of-mathematical-analysis).)